# Unknown TikZ/pgfplots error with external

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, luatex, tikz-external

I am trying to compile a large document (PhD thesis) and I have no problems compiling without using `external`, but as soon as I enable that feature, it has problems. So far I haven't found the answer in the various other similar topics. I have attempted to compile using both `lualatex` and `pdflatex`, both with `-shell-escape` enabled. The document itself compiles fine but I get errors when it gets to the `TikZ` images. This error is reproducible on my Windows machine using MikTeX as well as TeX Live on Ubuntu and running directly from a terminal as well as in TeXmaker.

Oddly enough, using an identical package list and syntax but only including the call to the `TikZ` file in the MWE produces a document that works successfully, so there is clearly something in my document or file system itself that prevents this from working properly when I am doing the actual thesis document.

Anyway, checking the `.log` file from my actual document reveals the following:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interact
ion=batchmode -jobname "img/cache/sac-thesis-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob
{sac-thesis}\input{sac-thesis}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'img/ca
che/sac-thesis-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify
that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-esca
pe'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the
command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'img/cache/sac-thesis-fi
gure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
```

When checking the `.log` file for the figure itself, it ends on the following error:

```
\@writefile{toc}{}
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmathsetlength ...\pgfmath@onquick #2\pgfmath@ 
                                                  {\begingroup \pgfmath@sele...
l.34 \end{tikzpicture}
```

For reference, here is my `.tikz` file that I am trying to compile. The `.pdf` referenced is a figure I built just using MATLAB and I am mostly placing annoatations on the figure in this instance (though I do have much more data-heavy `TikZ` pictures in there as well). You could honestly place any `.pdf` picture there to try it out and it wouldn't change the spirit of the problem here.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Styles
    [pointer/.style={thick}]

\node[anchor=south west] (diagram) at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=4.5in]{img/ch1/2mode/5DC-2mode.pdf}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(diagram.south east)},y={(diagram.north west)}]

        % Temporary gridlines
        %\draw[step=0.1,gray,ultra thin] (0,0) grid (1,1);

        % Wall label
        \draw {(0.5,0.08)} node[anchor=center,color=white] {Wall};

        % Trapped acoustic wave
        \draw {(0.66,0.2)} node[anchor=west,color=red] {Trapped acoustic wave};

        % Sonic line
        \draw {(0.55,0.29)} node[anchor=west] {Sonic line: $\overbar{M}^2 = 1$, $y = y_a$};

        % Inner layer
        \draw {(0.05,0.2)} node[anchor=west] {$\overbar{M} > 1$};

        % Outer layer
        \draw {(0.05,0.4)} node[anchor=west] {$\overbar{M} < 1$};

        % U(y)
        \draw {(0.45,0.66)} node[anchor=center,color=blue] {$U(y)$};

        % y-axis
        \draw {(0.24,0.94)} node[anchor=east] {$y$};

    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am honestly out of ideas here at the moment and would really like to `externalize` since I am going to have a LOT of figures in the document and compile times would get unruly.

Comment: have you tried to use `--shell-escape` instead of `-shell-escape`?

Comment: @Guido `-shell-escape` is correct on my system (TeX Live).

Comment: @Guido I tried that and it did not work. Same result.

Comment: Why is it concerned with writing to the `toc` file in what seems to be the middle of a TikZ picture? I find that the best way to use TikZ externalise is as follows: turn it off by default in the preamble and then selectively reenable it for just those figures which work. I also find it is best not to spend time trying to figure out why it doesn't work in particular cases. It is better to think of it as a matter of fate. That way, you don't waste time the feature is meant to save. At least for me, the feature is both fragile and fickle.

Comment: There are other possible approaches. `standalone` offers some support for externalisation. Or you can, of course, just compile to PDF and include the figures that way. Mostly, though, don't keep compiling your entire thesis. Split it up into chapters or whatever so you can work on one at a time. Then `\include` or `\input`. You should not need to compile the master document often at all - at least, not until right at the end when you are preparing to submit or finalising the formatting.

Comment: Strongly suggest not to compile `TikZ` graphics live, even with externalization. I initially tried that but placing content either as usual running text, a figure or a table is way faster for compiling. Also, my experience tells me although the global `.log` give the error for a specific externalized file, the error might actually be caused by content in the `.tex` file that includes said ext. file, most likely shortly before or after.

Comment: @cfr Rest assured I have the thesis split up into a whole host of files, often broken down into a few closely-related sections per `.tex` file and then `\input` them all. It makes it much easier to make changes and different versions of sections.

@henry yes, in this case it seems the error is not likely a problem with the `.TikZ` file itself since it compiles in a MWE, but in the `.tex` file wrapping it. I was just hoping someone here would have seen a similar error before and have some clue what might be causing it. Hmm...

Comment: It sounds as if some statement wrote expanded pgfmath code into an `.aux` file, although that stuff should never be expanded. This could be any `\label` (perhaps, just guessing). However, I cannot reproduce the issue at hand with a trivial tex file. Can you reduce the problem to some minimal working example? If that is infeasible, you can reduce it as much as possible and sent the result to me by mail. As package author of `external`, I would like to repair any problems of that sort.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I happened to have this exact same problem while using Tikz with `external`. For me there was one line in the template for my dissertation that was causing trouble: `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapleader}{\protect\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}}  % puts leader dots on chapters.` I moved this into the body of the document before the first chapter and this seems to have fixed things.